# Lists within dictionaries

Tags: list, dictionary

I'm using Python and trying to access some items in a list within a dictionary.   I do not need to loop, just need the item value.   Please see this:

```
<pre>
BROKER_INFO = {'AMERITRADE': {
           'file_info': {
             'broker_name'   : 'TD Ameritrade',
             'filename'      : 'ameritrade',
             'row_start'     : '1',
             'active'        : 'Y',
             'actions'       : 'Bought,Sold',
             'buy'           : 'Bought',
             'sell'          : 'Sold',
             'columns'       : [
               {'date': '0', 'action': '2', 'ticker': '4'}]
             }
</pre>
```

I'm looking to get the value to "date", "action", "ticker' within "columns", which is within "file_info" and "AMERITRADE".

I tried this:  BROKER_INFO[p_broker]['file_info']['columns']['action'], but no luck.

Many many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
BROKER_INFO[p_broker]['file_info']['columns'][0]['action']
```

Comment: Yes, thank you.   I'm quite used to Perl, so some of these are throwing me off.   Many thanks.